# xaml date format string ignored

Tags: wpf, xaml

My label is displaying '7/27/2010' instead of 'July 27, 2010'. Can someone please tell me why my markup code is apparently ignored?

```
RibbonLabel Content="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}, StringFormat='{}{0:MMMM d, yyyy}'}"
```

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The StringFormat property is only used if the binding is applied to a property of type String.  Since Content is of type object, it is not used.  Instead of setting the content to the date directly, set it to a TextBlock, and set the Text property of the TextBlock using a StringFormat:

```
<RibbonLabel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today},
        StringFormat='{}{0:MMMM d, yyyy}'}"/>
</RibbonLabel>
```

You could also define a DataTemplate for DateTime and then just set the content to Today:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0:MMMM d, yyyy}'}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...
<RibbonLabel Content="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}}">
```

---

EDIT: An even simpler solution is to use the ContentStringFormat property

```
<RibbonLabel Content="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}}"
    ContentStringFormat="{}{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" />
```